# UICollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths not re-using cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Inserting new cells into `collectionview` through `insertitemsatindexpaths` does not `deque` any cell. It creates new cells every time this function runs which increases memory usage. I am inserting around 400 items using this method in a loop and I am inserting one cell in each iteration of the loop. Or in other words, this is called once in each iteration.

Is there any solution for this so it doesn't create new cells?

```
if ([singletonObj.photosSortOrder isEqualToString:@"DESC"]) {
                [self.MNCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath   indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]]];
            }else{
                [self.MNCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath   indexPathForItem:[photos count]-1 inSection:0]]];
            }
```

This is called 400 times and each time it is called it inserts new cell rather than dequeing. Any one else observed this phenomenon?

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([cell.contentView.subviews count]>0) {
    [[cell.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
}

// create the image views
UIImageView *MNPhotosImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 78, 78)];
[MNPhotosImageView setImage:[self.collectionPhotos objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
[MNPhotosImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[MNPhotosImageView setClipsToBounds:YES];

[cell setBackgroundView:MNPhotosImageView];

if (cell.selected==YES && isInEditMode==YES) {


    UIImageView *checkMarkView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 78, 78)];
    [checkMarkView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [checkMarkView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkMark.png"]];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:checkMarkView];

}
//else{
//    [[cell.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
//}

MNPhotosImageView=nil;

return cell;
```

Comment: Can you show us the code ..?

Comment: if ([singletonObj.photosSortOrder isEqualToString:@"DESC"]) {
                    [self.MNCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]]];
                }else{
                    [self.MNCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[photos count]-1 inSection:0]]];
                }

Comment: put your code in question

Comment: You need to show the code where you register and sequence the cells...